# Redirect root to one backend pool and all other pages to another pool in Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I am trying to configure an Azure Application Gateway to direct the traffic for root (/ or /?querystring) to one backend pool say Pool1 and all other pages to another pool say Pool2.

I have tried setting the default backend pool to Pool1 and a path based rule for /* for Pool2. But this does not work. Similarly if I set Pool2 to be default, I can't set the path in path based rule to "/". So this also does not work.

Any help in this direction would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and I am getting the result successfully.***

- Ensure the supported Path pattern `/images*`  `/images/*` string provided to the path any text after the first? or #, these characters are not permitted in this context.
- I have created an application gateway with multiple backend target as default ganeralbackend and added path as **`/image*`** ’ as well as another backend pool is selected as another backend target as shown below: -

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/8ZOi5bY.png)]

Kindly check this **[MsDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-url-route-portal)**. To handle default scenarios, there's no need to include a special `/*` route rule. The multiple backend pool added in the routing rule takes care of this automatically.

- When you are creating an application gateway, try to create a default rule (*rule1*). This rule links with the default ***back-end HTTP settings,*** the ***default back-end pool,*** and the ***default*** ***listener***. After creating the gateway, you can modify the default rule's settings or add new ones.

Thus, When I tried to pass the Ip address, its works fine.

[image]

Comment: Hi @imran , I tried this today and my issue is that I need to have a setup where /, /home, /home/*  goes to one pool, /blog/*,/blog goes to another pool, and all other requests go to a third pool. I have managed everything else except for the / routing. Since path does not accept / , I am unable to add this rule.
I even tried setting the default pool to be where I want / to go and a path route /* to pool where all other requests should go. But still / goes to the all other requests pool. Hope I am making myself clear.